# Not able to get updated apk file in my project

Tags: android, apk

In my project when i test my application on my mobile device or emulator the app works properly and show all changes what i did with it but in **PROJECT -> bin** folder .apk file is not getting update? Help please.

Comment: What is this PROJECT -> bin folder? Is this a folder on your device?

Comment: in the folder of my Project

Answer (score 0):

Each time you make changes in the project which has the apk file earlier. You have to go through below process again:

**Project file>Right click>Android tools>Export signed/unsigned application package** and proceed until your current .apk is saved at target folder.

For the .apk in **bin** folder, sometimes Eclipse faces problems to update, you can 'Clean' and 'Build' project. Then run either in emulator or on your device. That will solve the issue at bin folder.

Good luck.

Comment: The unsigned apk should get updated automatically, when running the app on the emulator or the device through Eclipse.